# If condition evaluates to true in debugger/runtime but if block is not executed

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2019

I am running this simple code to calculate the median of an array obtained from merging two sorted arrays.

Weirdly, in Visual Studio 2019, the value in the first `if` block inside the loop is evaluating to true, but execution does not enter the `if` block.

```cpp
vector<int> nums1 = { 1,3 };
vector<int> nums2 = { 2 };
int collSize = nums1.size() + nums2.size();
int i = 0, currValue = -1, num1, num2;
int idx1 = -1, idx2 = -1;
while (i <= collSize / 2 + 1)
{
    // this statement evaluates to true
    if (idx1 < (nums1.size() - 1) && (nums1.at(idx1 + 1) < nums2.at(idx2 + 1)))
    {
        cout << "In Loop";
        idx1++;
        currValue = nums1.at(idx1);
    }
    else if (idx2 < (nums2.size() - 1))
    {
        idx2++;
        currValue = nums2.at(idx2);
    }

    if (i == (collSize / 2))
    {
        num1 = currValue;
        return currValue;
    }
    if (i == ((collSize / 2) + 1))
    {
        num2 = currValue;
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
if (collSize % 2 == 0)
{
       cout<<(num1+num2)/2;
}
else
{
   cout<<num1;
}
```

Comment: Try to validate your while statement.

Comment: `vector<T>` is not an array. And you should add parentheses around arithmetic operations - as it's not immediately obvious if the expression `collSize / 2 + 1` is `( collSize / 2 ) + 1` or `( collSize ) / ( 2 + 1 )`.

Comment: @Dai I have added parantheses in the code but the issue is I was not able to complete this algorithm as the first if condition itself is behaving strangely where `idx1 < (nums1.size() - 1) && (nums1.at(idx1 + 1) < nums2.at(idx2 + 1))` evaluates to true as in cout it prints 1 but the code inside if statement is never executed

Comment: @paladin while statement is running fine as statements inside while are executing the problem is with the first if condition in the loop

Comment: @Himanshu Shishodia You've written the following statement, _"the value in the first **if** block inside the loop is evaluating to true, but execution does not enter the **if** block"_. If this statement is true, it implicates/means, that the **while**-loop-condition isn't true, otherwise your statement isn't correct.

Comment: @paladin the statement inside the while i.e. `i <= collSize / 2 + 1` evaluates to true let's say for the first iteration then in first iteration statement inside if block i.e. `idx1 < (nums1.size() - 1) && (nums1.at(idx1 + 1) < nums2.at(idx2 + 1))` also evaluates to true as I can see that when I print this value in the console but issue is execution is not entering  the if block

Comment: Verify that your **while**-loop-condition is true, don't assume! `while(...) {cout << "First line in while-loop"; /* your other stuff */}`.

Comment: @paladin verified it is working, checked with debugging the code and it does enter the while loop but not the if condition

Comment: I suggest using intermediate variables rather than using anonymous expressions. That way you can also print-out results when debugging. That said, if you say the program operates differently when debugging vs. running normally that's a hint you've got UB caused by using zeroed out memory somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. `nums1.size()` returns an *unsigned integer* which you compare to a *signed integer*, but *signed integer* -1 is the highest value for *unsigned integer*. So your term `idx1 < (nums1.size() - 1)` is in real `4294967295 < 1`, which always becomes *false*.

Comment: the workaround of putting nums1.size() into an int before doing the comparison did solved my problem. But still can't figure out why the expression was printing to true in console while always evaluating to false as per your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

A standard is that container classes defined by STL (std::vector, std::array, etc.) in C++ return size_t or std::size_t for the `size()` function. The basic definition for `size_t` is unsigned int, but this can [vary by implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t). The maximum value of unsigned int can also vary based on the compiler and computer architecture based on the word size, it is guaranteed to be at least 2^16 - 1 and on current computers and architectures may be as large as 2^64 - 1.

One way you could have caught this problem is to use the `-wall` switch that enables all warnings in C++ compilers, that would possibly have identified a type mismatch between nums1.size() and idx1.

The type `size_t` should be preferred for indexes since it won't have a negative value although the index may still be out of range if it is larger than the current capacity of the container.